# Como iterar en un request para webscraping

Tags: python, web, scraping

Tengo que hacer un request con los codigos del csv (los tengo en una lista) pero no he tenido éxito.

```
import requests #para obtener data HTML
import bs4
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_csv('tags.csv')
x.head()
tags = x.loc[:,'Código']
b = list(tags)

for gt in b:
   res = requests.get(url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search/", params = { "specials": 1, "tags": gt })
```

Comment: Puedes indicar mas espcificamente en que estas teniendo problemas? que mensajes de error recibes, o que resultados esperados no aparecen

Comment: Detalla mas tu problema